# simple if else condition in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to echo a string based upon a cookie condition, the code is shown below:

```
<?php setcookie('a12cookie', '1'); ?>
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie'])) { ?>
<?php echo "hello"; ?>

<?php } ?>

<?php else { ?>

<?php echo "bye"; ?>

<?php } ?>
```

I have no problem with it displaying "hello", its just when I add the else condition I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home/looksr5/public_html/cookie1.php on line 6
```

I know I've missed something out in line 6, cant figure out what.

Comment: there is wrong. you have an buffer output between `}` and `else`, remove `?> <?php`

Comment: in fact it is very starnge idea to open/close `<?php`  on each line of code!

Comment: Note: your code will NOT work as expected. $_COOKIE is populated at script startup, and then NOT TOUCHED AGAIN by php. The cookie you just set will NOT be in $_COOKIE until the **NEXT** page load.

Comment: @MarcB what the reason to immidiatly check `$_COOKIE` after set, I think it is not expected that `setcookie()`  updates the array, anyway it is a very strange code, and it is very hard to say what author means writing this. It is remember me early postmodern poetry.

Comment: @eicto: far too many questions on the site from people who DO expect the superglobals to update themselves.

Answer (score 3):

Just put the `else` after the `}`
Like this:

`<?php } else { ?>`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
<?php setcookie('a12cookie', '1'); ?>
<?php echo (isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie']) ? "Hello" : "Bye");?>
```

*The only case where I like using the ternary operator is when I have simple conditional echo statements like yours.

Also, when using PHP as a language for presentation, it can often be preferable to use its alternative syntax. This will allow you to very easily insert other presentation.

```
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie'])):?>
Hello
<?php else:?>
Bye
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to close the php tags after `}` if you intend to use an `else` statement. Your code should look like this:

```
...
<?php } else { ?>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like:

```
<?php setcookie('a12cookie', '1');
if (isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie'])) {
    echo "hello"; 
  } else {
  echo "bye";
}
```

or at least:

```
<?php setcookie('a12cookie', '1');
if (isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie'])) {
 ?>hello<?php } else {
 ?>bye<?php }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also write, sometimes it's easier to read

```
<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['a12cookie'])): ?>
    <?php echo "hello" ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo "bye" ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Unless you are using variable, why would you reopen PHP tags just to echo a string?

Comment: Thank you for that question ;) - imho the best choice for this short snippet is to use the ternary operator "echo (isset(...))?'hello':'bye'" - otherwise I wanted to state out that readability is more important than trying to keep the code as small as possible. Usually you'll have a mixture of PHP and for example HTML in your view-representation. Therefore it would be good to make a strict demarcation of the representation logic and direct output.

Comment: aaaand it seems I did not get the point of your question. Yes - it makes no sense to echo a simple string.